# Security: Patched 1.7.0.2 versus 1.9.2.2

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, upgrade, security, patches, ce-1.9.2.2

I have three sites running 1.7.0.2 all fully patched and updated.  Modules all written the 'proper' way (with a couple of small exceptions).  The sites are all pretty much clones of each other.

There is a new site coming - I'm wondering whether I should upgrade them all to the latest version of 1.x (1.9.2.2 at time of writing) and build the new site on that too.  It will mean a lot of testing, the sites do brisk business.

I also wondering whether it's worth that effort or whether I should just use our existing codebase and launch the new site on patched 1.7.0.2. Then focus the development effort on the migration to v2 (I'm aware that will be a much more serious project of course). The real question then is -

**Is a fully patched 1.7.0.2 less secure than 1.9.2.2?**

I'm not interested in any new features of 1.9.2.2, just whether running on patched 1.7.0.2 buys me enough time to re-develop these sites on v2.

I'm interested to know any thoughts.

Comment: there is one rule = if it works then dont touch it.  work on your Mv2 design, after you just upgrade your store and convert it to Mv2

Comment: @MagenX - Thanks, I love this comment. Very pragmatic, it's kinda what I wanted to hear too.  I agree with the sentiment entirely.

Comment: You are being a little bit pessimistic thinking your extensions + custom code will not be compatible after you upgrade to latest Magento. Try this on a dev server and see what happens.

Comment: @DannyZ - You make a good point here.  I think working with Magento for so long must have 'pessimised' me ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: Nice question!

I'd say a fully patched 1.7.0.2 is as secure as a new 1.9.2.2.
As long as there are still security patches released for 1.7.0.2 you're good to go with it.

So I think it makes sense to continue with 1.7.0.2 and use the time to plan and develop your new shop with Magento 2.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer Anna.  I'm pleased this is your take on it, it reassures me.  I am always seeing comments like 'You should upgrade', 'You need to upgrade' etc from users around the main SO site but nobody ever cites a source for why this should be the case. Cheers!

Comment: Of course you should upgrade ;-) It makes also sense in terms of new features, bugfixes etc. But just from a security point of few a fully patched shop is ok too I think.

Comment: i was waiting till someone will flag this question as duplicate... :)